# Can we use verbs like 'miss' and 'love' without the pronouns?

Tags: pronouns, idiomatic-language, subject-pronoun-drop

Can we use verbs like 'miss' and 'love' without the pronouns? I've heard people say things like

> Miss you

> Love you

I don't know why, but this doesn't sound idiomatic or grammatical to me.

Answer (score 6):

It is very idiomatic in informal speech to leave out a pronoun at the start of a sentence if it would be clear from context.  The practice is called [*subject pronoun drop* or **diary drop**](https://awweir.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/weir-ug-diss.pdf):

> Sentences  in  English  are  generally  considered  to  require  overt  subjects.
>   In  a   standard  description   of  English,   (1 a)  below  would   be  considered
>   grammatical, while (1 b) would be considered ungrammatical:
>   (1)
>   (a)  I walked the dog yesterday.
>   (b)  Walked the dog yesterday.
>
> But in fact this is not true. (1 b), and sentences like it lacking subject pronouns,
>   are  in  fact  common  in  colloquial  spoken  English.   This  phenomenon  has  a
>   written counterpart in “diary drop” (Haegeman, 1990, 1997; Haegeman and
>   Ihsane,  1999,  2001);  subject  pronouns  can  frequently  be  dropped  in  certain
>   registers of written English, such as diaries but also including text messages,
>   emails, and other forms of informal communication...

Comment: ' Love you' sounds normal to me but miss you does not :-/

Comment: @user68401 "Love you" is ubiquitous, but "miss you" is common as well.

Comment: It might help to add that diary drop requires that the missing subject be obvious from context. In a diary, for example, we can safely assume it is “I”, which would be horribly repetitive (nearly every sentence) if not dropped.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't. If the people were trying to be grammatical then they would need to begin each sentence with the subject, namely "I". But when expressing such emotions, grammar is probably not at the forefront of their minds.